# Custom GET Parameters In Plugin's Admin Page

Tags: plugin-development

In my plugin's options page, I'd like to have custom GET parameters. WordPress already has a `?page=<slug>` GET parameter, so simply linking to something like `?myparameter=value` won't work.

I though of reading the `page` parameter, and then linking to something like: `?page=<slug>&myparameter=value`. This seems workable, but I don't know if its the best practice. The complexity of my plugin really doesn't warrant sub-pages for now.

So is this the best practice or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using [`add_query_arg()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg):

```
  $url = add_query_arg(array(
            'foo'=>'bar',
            'custom'=>'var',
            'page'=>'myadminpage'
           ), admin_url('admin.php'));
```

The second argument, `admin_url('admin.php')`, is optional - and if omitted it uses the url of the current page you are on.